# 1000 W Arduino dimmer

Tags: arduino, pwm, dimmer

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]everybody, I have a project which is to dim 1000 W halogen light connected to Arduino. I used this circuit which is working fine with 100 W halogen light but when I connect 1000 W light the transistor burns once I on the circuit I am a beginner so forgive me.[image]

This is the components I used

Bridge rectifier: 6 amp 400 Volt 
Transistor: IRF740
Optocoupler: 4n35
resistor 4.7k
resistor 100k 1 Watt 
resistor 6k8 1/4 Watt
Capacitor 100uF 400 Volt
Zener 15 Volt 0.5 Watt
diode 10A10

Comment: Start by making a schematic, you will get burned for simply posting a layout.

Comment: my bad sorry i added

Comment: In addition to Szidor's answer below, I'd like to say that the traces are too thin (Assuming the second image shows the actual layout).

Comment: Noted with thanks i will edit the pcb design

Comment: The schematic is not correct (yet). According the layout, only the bridge is connected to the AC source. All other components should be connected to the rectified part of the bridge. Double check the bridge rectifier connections as well.

Comment: that is a horrible schematic ... why are there zig-zags at bottom end of R3 and at the top end of D3? ... why is L1 not placed at the right side of the schematic above Q1 and without any diagonal lines? ... V1 should be placed on left of all other components.

Comment: Note that the "source" (emitter) of your FET should probably go to the emitter of your opto-coupler, and effectively that node is a "rectified working ground" of your semiconductor circuit. Note that this "inner ground" is really pretty live, you should by no means touch any part of the circuit during operation, including the TO220 heat transfer pad (probably attached to the "drain" / collector of your FET).

Comment: The AC input terminals should be connected to the nodes in the Graetz bridge where "an anode meets a cathode" = those two nodes can accept either polarity = accept AC input. The two nodes where two cathodes meet, or two anodes meet, those are your rectified DC output = this is where you connect your circuit.

Comment: Can you imagine driving a 1.3 Hp motor with this puny series regulator? Both a Halogen lamp and a DC motor have 10x start current.  Your FET easily overheat from the 500W series power loss @ 50% dim.  This is a very naive design.  Linear control will always fail.

Comment: 1000W is quite high. Shouldn't you prepend some sort of PFC?

Comment: I am sorry but what is PFC, beginner here

Comment: PFC is Power Factor Correction, depending on the region where you are, it could be that you must have it.

Comment: I just want to mention it again the circuit is working perfectly for 100w load

Comment: @tofi PFC is required not because the circuit won't work without it. PFC is required for devices that use switching and draw huge power above some limit. For example ATX power supplies MUST have PFC because they draw couple of hundreds of Watts. Without PFC you will pollute power lines with high current noise. It is the same as car with diesel engine is required to have exhaust filter. Yes, the car will work without this filter, but will pollute the air with nasty particles.

Comment: The schematic is much improved. Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar that you don't need an account and that your editable schematic is saved directly into your post. That has the advantage that we can copy it into our answers and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a transistor with much lower Ron. 1000W at 400V is 2.5A. Your transistor's Ron is .55 Ohm. That implies ~3W dissipated power, which is too much for a TO-220 package without a major heatsink.
You should use a transistor with an Ron in the 10-20mOhm range.

Comment: thank you Szidor
Would you mind if can suggest a transistor with appropriate Ron to handle this kind of load plz

Comment: is this transistor will do SIHG460B

Comment: Ron still too large. It should be 0.1ohm max, but I would choose half that for safety and lifetime margin.

Comment: Ok if I Change the load to 500w what would the be Ron

Comment: Is this good to use Stw26nm50?

Comment: This has 100-120mohm. Will work but will be still quite hot.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just to help you with your schematic.

[image]

*Figure 0. OP's schematic.*

- It is badly laid out making it difficult to follow the schema of the circuit. There are numerous unnecessary kinks and cross-overs.
- BR1 is installed incorrectly. When V1 goes negative BR1 will short-circuit the mains supply and will be destroyed (as there is no fuse).
- Q1's gate is not referenced to the same point of the circuit as its source so the gate-source voltage will be all over the place.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv7zkv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's schematic redrawn with BR1 orientation corrected and fuse donated.*

A major redesign is required.

Comment: I believe your schematic is wrong. According to the PCB, everything happens *after* the +/- terminals of the Graetz bridge. The mains input only feeds the bridge. And IMO that's the way it *should* be.

Comment: As stated in the caption of Figure 1, I've redrawn the schematic. I have not converted the board layout to a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot exclude that the circuit can principally work (as per PCB layout; your schematic is currently wrong, at the time of this writing).

The IRF740 should have plenty enough heat dissipation capability for 3W of continuous power (its abs max is given at 125W continuous), so I wouldn't be very concerned about RdsON, as long as the IRF740 FET is genuine (not fake), and as long as you provide adequate heatsink. For 3W, typical manufacturers would use something the size of a matchbox. I myself would rather go for something the size of a cigarette pack. Ultra-low RdsON goes hand in hand with ultra-low permitted voltage (Vds) so don't let those 5 milliOhm FET's get on your nerves, they can only sustain 40 Vots or so.

Looking at the gate drive circuit, I would say that the resistive pull-up (when combined with the gate's own capacitance) might be a little too slow. And the unnecessarily long crossover period might result in extra thermal stress on the FET: periods where the gate voltage is just around the opening threshold, there is non-zero current, but compared to the cold lightbulb, the FET's resistance is still high, so the current multiplies with pretty much the whole rail voltage, giving a nasty instantaneous power product. Even if those transitional periods are relatively short, and even though the FET does have some peak current (and power) capacity, the heat pulses might be too harsh on the FET.

Note that a cold bulb has quite a low resistance. It only reaches its nominal resistance as it heats up. The "cold" resistance can easily be 1/20th of the nominal value that you calculate by V/I (nominal). Thus, the start-up peak current is that many times the nominal current when the bulb is already hot.
Not sure if it's 20 or more like 50 times...

[image: 100W / 240V bulb instant startup, current sensed through an improvised current transformer = just a ferite torus with a couple turns for the secondary winding]

According to the oscillogram, this filament heat-up peak apparently fits within one half-period of 50Hz mains !

So if this gets combined with the sluggish turn-on, arranged by the weak resistive pull-up in the FET gate... you get the idea.

To be on the safe side, I'd probably design the circuit such that the semiconductors would have a stable = filtered source of something between 12 an 20 V DC, and would contain a proper gate driver, including an active "high side switch", to allow for a fast turn-on in the power FET. In this respect, triacs/thyristors are easier to handle, in that once you cross the opening threshold, the rest of the "switch-on" happens in an avalanchey fashion (positive feedback inside the part).

Next, any switching silicon for (not only) mains voltages should have the nominal permitted operating voltage optimally at twice the actual operating voltage. I.e., in your case, a FET or TRIAC for 600V is barely acceptable, parts for 800V are okay, 1000-1200V were even better. And yes the RdsON will be worse (other factors equal) but you've read my opinion about RdsON alone above. Apart from the voltage durability (which doesn't make much sense, theoretically, for resistive loads), the higher permitted voltage may also indicate a better capacity for short pulses of peak thermal abuse. At least such is my explanation for the observed better reliability in practical operation.

And another question is, "what happens if a lightbulb breaks". Often the arc inside the bulb effectively shorts the terminals, which can result in an even mightier peak than the turn-on pulse. Exactly how much the peak current is, that depends on the cross-section / length / condition of your mains wiring, and the distance from your neighborhood's high-volt trafo. I've seen this being a problem in a theater, running a couple dozen dimmer-controlled halogen lighting channels, where the high-volt transformer was about 20 meters away...
I've seen those events being a problem with a 40A / 600V triac. With a 40A / 800V triac, the failures were not as frequent, but still there were some.
The dimmer was specced for 3 kW = about 12 A per channel, and contained 40A triacs. And had a problem when a bulb would break (the triac would break down irreversibly = would keep conducting).
Another dimmer specced at 5 kW per channel (about 20A) at that same site was equipped with 90A (nominal) triac modules, and that one doesn't have a problem
with broken 1kW bulbs.
Note that the 90A triac modules are substantially bigger and heavier than the 40A model. (And the former had old-school fuses, while the latter had electro-magnetic circuit breakers.) I suspect that what really matters is to survive the short-circuit current from the high-volt Trafo until the first zero-crossing comes. The nominal wattage of the bulb and the doesn't matter much. The details of its internal construction do matter. (If the filament breaks, what are the chances of catching an arc leading to a short circuit at the terminals of the bulb.) The rest is down to the "thermal abuse capacity until breakdown" (in Joules) of the semiconductor switching device, and the short circuit current available from the neighborhood trafo.

Note that your circuit would use some EMI filtering, say between the mains terminals and the rectifier bridge.

Also note that if you use a FET (rather than a Thyristor/Triac), it would be feasible to implement a current limit or a reversible "electronic overcurrent fuse", which would however make the circuit even more complicated. Thyristors/Triac only turn off when the current goes through 0.

Comment: Wow 
In my case, you advise me to go with thyristor?

Comment: "Advise" is not exactly the way I would put it :-) It is a possibility. Both transistors and thyristors/triacs have their upsides and downsides. Yet another option is an IGBT = a BJT transistor with an isolator in one package. Obviously you would need a different circuit schematic and a different PCB for each option. Thyristors or triacs are the classic part to use in dimmers. Turned on by a short pulse at the phase angle desired, it will shut off all by itself when the current crosses a zero. IGBT's are transistors, so they can be turned on and off at your discretion (zero crossing at best).